# Adding child nodes to existing tree and linking them to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Home.aspx page in ASP.NET and have created a tree using the TreeView control from toolbox. Have added all the nodes(root and child) in design mode. I want to have  parent nodes as it is and add child nodes through code. Used below code in Page Load, but it gives compile time error

```
TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add("testChild");
```

The number of nodes that can be added to a parent are not fixed(dynamic) and should be hyperlinked to another page.

Comment: *but it gives compile time error* and what is that? mind posting it as well

Comment: Error shows a red squiggly line on "testChild" and the error message is:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode' ,